# How to get selected value after clone with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-select, selectedvalue

Here is my **complete** testing code,which failed to get the value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
    <title>Job Search</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#test').click(function(){
                $('#container').clone().attr('id', 'container2').find('select').each(function() {
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    var value = $elem.val();
                    alert(value);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <select>
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
        <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
        <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
        <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
        <option value="Management">Management</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="test" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to insert the cloned element to DOM?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#container').clone().attr('id', 'container2').find('select > option').each(function() {
                var $elem = $(this);
                var value = $elem.val();
                alert(value);
            });
```

Changed the selector in find method to select > option from select.

Also why are you cloning the element if you are not going to append it to the DOM.

To get the selected value of the cloned element you can use

```
$('#container').clone().attr('id', 'container2').find('select > option:selected').val()
```

If you need to insert the cloned element to the DOM you can use

```
$('#container').clone().attr('id', 'container2').appendTo("body")
```

and full code for getting the selected option value after inserting the cloned element to the DOM

```
$('#container').clone().attr('id', 'container2').appendTo("body").find('select > option:selected').val()
```

Complete code for the button click

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#test').click(function(){
                $('#container').clone().attr('id', 'container2').appendTo("body").find('select > option:selected').each(function() {
                    alert ( $(this).val());
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: $('#selectList option:selected').val()? Or is there no difference?

Comment: I updated the post,I suspect it has something to do with the clone()

Comment: It iterated all option values,but I want to directly get the selected option value of <select>,is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you need to insert the cloned element to the DOM you can use appendTo method.

Comment: Do you know why can't directly get value of <select> after clone()?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it, and this works.

```
$container.find('select').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: I've put all my testing code up.You can see that it's not working when click the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select > option:selected').val();
```

To iterate over all select elements on the page and alert the selected options' values:

```
$('select > option:selected').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The `clone` loses the selected value.

What I did was, while working with the clone I look-up the actual element with same `id` and get its value.

i.e. **Get the value from the actual element instead of the clone**

Like below,

```
var selectedOption = $('#' + cloneOfSelect.attr('id')).find('option:selected');

var selectedValue = selectedOption.val(); //or .text() for display value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function studentInfo() {
var studentInfoUrl = ".../studentInfourl"; 
var multiTags=$('.copy');
var name= multiTags.find("select.form-control#name").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
var dob= multiTags.find("input.form-control#dob").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
var gender= multiTags.find("#gender:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
var collage= multiTags.find(".input.form-control#collage").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
var cloneName= '';
var cloneDob= '';
var cloneGender= '';
var cloneCollage= '';
var arr=[];
if($('.copy').length<=2){
      cloneName= name.split(',');
        cloneDob= dob.split(',');
        cloneGender= gender.split(',');
         cloneCollage= collage.split(',');
}
    for(var i=0;i<$('.copy').length ;i++){
        var studentInfo = {
                studentId  :   $("#studentId").val(),
                name       :   cloneName[i],
                dob        :   cloneDob[i],
                gender     :   cloneGender[i],
                collage    :   cloneCollage[i],
        };
        arr.push(studentInfo);
    }
    var astudentJsonRequest = JSON.stringify(arr);
    alert(arr);
    $.ajax({
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : astudentJsonRequest ,
        cache : false,
        type : "POST",
        url : studentInfoUrl ,
        success : function(data){}
```

});
}

Here i can get the individual input type values form clone table and then using the split method to split these values and after i find the length of clone table and assign these values to corresponding bean values.